# Exception when getting attribute constructor arguments with multiple enum arrays

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I was playing with attributes and reflection when I found a strange case. The following code gave me an exception at runtime when I try to get constructor arguments of custom attributes.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    [Test(new[] { Test.Foo }, null)]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = typeof(Program);
        var method = type.GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var attribute = method.GetCustomAttributesData()[0].ConstructorArguments;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public enum Test
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute(Test[] valuesOne, Test[] valuesTwo)
    {
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be the parameters passed to the `Test` attribute constructor. If one of them is null, `ConstructorArguments` throw an exception. The exception is `ArgumentException` with `name` as exception message.

Here is the stack trace from `ConstructorArguments` call:

```
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByNameUsingCARules(String name, RuntimeModule scope)
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeTypedArgument.ResolveType(RuntimeModule scope, String typeName)
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeTypedArgument..ctor(RuntimeModule scope, CustomAttributeEncodedArgument encodedArg)
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.get_ConstructorArguments()
```

If I set a non null value to each parameters there is no exception. It seems to only happen with enum array. If I add another parameter such as string and set them to null, there is no problem.

A solution could be to always pass a value such as an empty array but here I would like to keep the ability to pass null value because it has a special meaning in my case.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug to me. Unclear at the moment whether it's a CLR bug or a Roslyn bug. Will raise the bat signal to Roslyn devs...

Comment: compiled on linux with dmcs and executed with mono, it works without throwing any exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the [structure of the blob where the custom attribut](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-custom-attribute-encoding/)e is specified.

> Array values start with an integer indicating the number of elements
>   in the array, then the item values concatentated together.
>
> A null array is represented using a length of -1.
>
> An enum argument is represented using the byte 0x55 **followed by a**
>   **string specifying the name** and assembly of the enum type.

Unfortunately, what happens if you pass an array of enum as null is that enum name is lost.

In terms of native debugging, this is the relevant source code

```
    else if (encodedType == CustomAttributeEncoding.Array)
    {                
        encodedType = encodedArg.CustomAttributeType.EncodedArrayType;
        Type elementType;

        if (encodedType == CustomAttributeEncoding.Enum)
        {
            elementType = ResolveType(scope, encodedArg.CustomAttributeType.EnumName);
        }
```

And this is how the c.tor parameter is instantiated

```
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            m_ctorParams[i] = new CustomAttributeCtorParameter(InitCustomAttributeType((RuntimeType)parameters[i].ParameterType));
```

The problem is that the an enum value is simply represented using the underlying value (basically an int): 
the CLR implementation (`RuntimeType`) has to look at the *attribute constructor signature* to interpret it, but custom *attribute signatures* differ quite a bit from other types of signatures encoded in a .NET assembly.

More specifically, *without* a defined `encodedArrayType` (from `GetElementType`), the following if becomes false (and `enumName` remains null)

```
        if (encodedType == CustomAttributeEncoding.Array)
        {
            parameterType = (RuntimeType)parameterType.GetElementType();
            encodedArrayType = CustomAttributeData.TypeToCustomAttributeEncoding(parameterType);
        }

        if (encodedType == CustomAttributeEncoding.Enum || encodedArrayType == CustomAttributeEncoding.Enum)
        {
            encodedEnumType = TypeToCustomAttributeEncoding((RuntimeType)Enum.GetUnderlyingType(parameterType));
            enumName = parameterType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
        }
```

### ILDASM

You can find the .custom instance of the Main from ildasm

in case of

```
[Test(new[] { Test.Bar }, null)]
static void Main(string[] args)
```

it is (notice the `FF FF FF FF` meaning an **array size** of **-1**)

```
.custom instance void TestAttribute::.ctor(valuetype Test[],
                                         valuetype Test[]) = 
( 01 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 )
```

while for

```
[Test(new[] { Test.Bar }, new Test[] { })]
static void Main(string[] args)
```

you see

```
.custom instance void TestAttribute::.ctor(valuetype Test[],
                                          valuetype Test[]) = 
( 01 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 )
```

### CLR virtual machine

Finally, you have confirmation that the [CLR virtual machine](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/customattribute.cpp#L1624-L1647) is reading the blob of a custom attribute into an array only when the size is different from -1

```
case SERIALIZATION_TYPE_SZARRAY:      
typeArray:
{
    // read size
    BOOL isObject = FALSE;
    int size = (int)GetDataFromBlob(pCtorAssembly, SERIALIZATION_TYPE_I4, nullTH, pBlob, endBlob, pModule, &isObject);
    _ASSERTE(!isObject);

    if (size != -1) {
        CorSerializationType arrayType;
        if (th.IsEnum()) 
            arrayType = SERIALIZATION_TYPE_ENUM;
        else
            arrayType = (CorSerializationType)th.GetInternalCorElementType();

        BASEARRAYREF array = NULL;
        GCPROTECT_BEGIN(array);
        ReadArray(pCtorAssembly, arrayType, size, th, pBlob, endBlob, pModule, &array);
        retValue = ObjToArgSlot(array);
        GCPROTECT_END();
    }
    *bObjectCreated = TRUE;
    break;
}
```

In conclusion, in this case the contructor arguments are not instantiated inside C#, so they can be retrieved *only from the constructor itself*: in fact the custom attribute is created (via `CreateCaObject`) in the CLR virtual machine by calling its contructor with *unsafe pointers* (directly to the *blob*)

```
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    private static unsafe extern Object _CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, byte** ppBlob, byte* pEndBlob, int* pcNamedArgs);
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    private static unsafe Object CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, ref IntPtr blob, IntPtr blobEnd, out int namedArgs)
    {
        byte* pBlob = (byte*)blob;
        byte* pBlobEnd = (byte*)blobEnd;
        int cNamedArgs; 
        object ca = _CreateCaObject(module, ctor, &pBlob, pBlobEnd, &cNamedArgs);
        blob = (IntPtr)pBlob;
        namedArgs = cNamedArgs;
        return ca;
    }
```

### Possible bug

The critical point for a possible bug is

```
            unsafe
            {
                ParseAttributeArguments(
                    attributeBlob.Signature,
                    (int)attributeBlob.Length,
                    ref customAttributeCtorParameters,
                    ref customAttributeNamedParameters,
                    (RuntimeAssembly)customAttributeModule.Assembly);
            }
```

implemented in

```
FCIMPL5(VOID, Attribute::ParseAttributeArguments, void* pCa, INT32 cCa,
        CaArgArrayREF* ppCustomAttributeArguments,
        CaNamedArgArrayREF* ppCustomAttributeNamedArguments,
        AssemblyBaseObject* pAssemblyUNSAFE)
```

maybe the following could be reviewed...

```
    cArgs = (*ppCustomAttributeArguments)->GetNumComponents();

    if (cArgs)
    {        
        gc.pArgs = (*ppCustomAttributeArguments)->GetDirectPointerToNonObjectElements();
```

### Proposed Fix

You can find this issue restyled to CoreCLR with a suggested [FIX](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/7346#issuecomment-249391605) from github.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous answer I tracked down how the Enum name is lost by the current standard .Net code of mscorlib... and so the cause of this exception

Now I want only show a concrete custom reengineering of the constructor arguments, based on your specific Test enum definition (so the following is not standard enough to be proposed as an actual improvement, but it is only a complementary part of the explanation)

```
var dataCust = method.GetCustomAttributesData()[0];
var ctorParams = dataCust.GetType().GetField("m_ctorParams", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var reflParams = ctorParams.GetValue(dataCust);

var results = new List<Test[]>();
bool a = reflParams.GetType().IsArray;
if (a)
{
    var mya = reflParams as Array;
    for (int i = 0; i < mya.Length; i++)
    {
        object o = mya.GetValue(i);
        ctorParams = o.GetType().GetField("m_encodedArgument", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        reflParams = ctorParams.GetValue(o);
        var array = reflParams.GetType().GetProperty("ArrayValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        reflParams = array.GetValue(reflParams);

        if (reflParams != null)
        {
            var internal_array = reflParams as Array;
            var resultTest = new List<Test>();
            foreach (object item in internal_array)
            {
                ctorParams = item.GetType().GetField("m_primitiveValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                reflParams = ctorParams.GetValue(item);
                resultTest.Add((Test)long.Parse(reflParams.ToString()));
            }
            results.Add(resultTest.ToArray());
        } else
        {
            results.Add(null);
        } 

    }
}
```

so `results` will contain a list of the `Test[]` arguments used in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is a .NET bug!

But if you need a workaround you can copy the constructor args to members and access like `method.GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>().valuesOne` etc.